# blueprintjs with laravel 5.2 and webpack with elixir

Tags: webpack, laravel-5, laravel-elixir, blueprintjs

based on feedback from @michael-jungo, I've rewritten this question here: [laravel-elixir v6 sass-loader imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594792/elixir-v6-sass-loader-imports)

---

I'm on laravel 5.2 and want to used [blueprintjs](http://blueprintjs.com/) which [uses webpack tilde alias in paths](https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/blob/master/packages/core/src/common/_font-imports.scss#L6), e.g.

```
@import "~bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/bourbon";
```

I understand therefore that I need to use webpack rather than browserify in elixir. Laravel 5.2 doesn't ship with elixir version 6 which is where webpack support is added. I can't upgrade to laravel > 5.3 because I can't easily upgrade my php version on our production server. So I'm trying to get elixir 6 working with laravel 5.2 so that I can use webpack and set this alias so that I can use blueprint.

**My Error**

```
    gulp watch
    /path/to/project/gulpfile.js:3
    Elixir.webpack.mergeConfig({
    ^

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'mergeConfig' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/si/cesg/projects/mason-presentation-admin/gulpfile.js:3:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at execute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/lib/versioned/^3.7.0/index.js:24:18)
    at Liftoff.handleArguments (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/index.js:149:63)
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
    var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

    Elixir.webpack.mergeConfig({
        alias: {'~': path.resolve(__dirname)}
    });

    elixir(function(mix) {
        mix.sass('app.scss');
        mix.webpack('index.js');
        mix.version(['css/app.css', 'js/index.js']);
    });
```

You can see that without the mergeConfig block I get issues with the unrecognised ~ alias in blueprintjs

```
    { Error: node_modules/@blueprintjs/core/src/common/_font-imports.scss
        Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ~bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/bourbon
```

with the following scss

```
    $icon-font-path: "~@blueprintjs/core/resources/icons";
    @import "node_modules/@blueprintjs/core/src/blueprint.scss";
```

**for reference, here's my package.json**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "laravel-elixir": "6.0.0-15",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@blueprintjs/core": "^1.10.0",
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.20.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.22.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bourbon": "^4.3.3",
    "form-serialize": "^0.7.1",
    "history": "^3.0.0",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.1.0",
    "normalize-scss": "^6.0.0",
    "pluralize": "^3.1.0",
    "query-string": "^4.3.2",
    "react": "^15.4.0",
    "react-addons-create-fragment": "^15.4.2",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.4.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.7",
    "react-confirm": "^0.1.14",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.0",
    "react-global-configuration": "^1.0.1",
    "react-paginate": "^4.1.1",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.6",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.7",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "spinkit": "^1.2.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: I should say that other than the sass compilation, webpack is working fine with js.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [elixir v6 sass-loader imports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594792/elixir-v6-sass-loader-imports)

Answer (score 2):

The tilde `~` is not an alias, but is used to import from `node_modules` in a Sass file, as described in [sass-loader imports](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#imports). But you're wrongly aliasing it to the current directory (where the `gulpfile.js` is), and then this module resolution fails. So remove that alias and it should work fine.

And you can also make use of that syntax in your scss file instead of specifying `node_modules`:

```
@import "~@blueprintjs/core/src/blueprint.scss";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Without the alias in my gulpfile I get "Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ~@blueprintjs/core/src/blueprint.scss". Is there some sort of configuration that I need to do for webpack to understand where ~ maps to for sass-loader imports? Is the fact that I'm using elixir complicating things? The fact that Elixir.webpack is not an object also seems like a smell, even if I shouldn't need to add webpack config in this instance.

Comment: Do I need to do something with custom loader config in elixir? I'm not sure what vue is, and I don't have anything referencing vue or sass-loader in my package.json. Is any of this relevant?

Comment: I honestly have no clue what `elixir.sass` does, but it doesn't look like it's using webpack, therefore that syntax doesn't work. So maybe you could use the already processed css instead of the Sass version (in `dist/` instead of `src/`): `@import "node_modules/@blueprintjs/core/dist/blueprint.css";`

Comment: OK, that works, but of course it means I can't set any variables prior to compiling blueprint sass. So the issue here seems to be specifically about how to use sass-loader imports with elixir 6.

Comment: If you want to use `.scss` I'd recommend to do it with webpack directly, so not using the `elixir.sass`, which presumably just processes Sass. Instead you'd import it in your JavaScript entry point as described in [Code Splitting - CSS](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-css/). This requires you to configure [sass-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#sass-loader).